# add a custom function to all Model in AdonisJS

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

I want to add custom function to all of my **Model** how can do this?
I have a **ListOption** function and I want to use it in all **Model** I try to write **MyModel** and extend **Model** when use this method my hook not work any more and I want to use another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Model = use('Model')

class MyModel extends Model {
  static _bootIfNotBooted () {
    if (this.name !== 'MyModel') {
      super._bootIfNotBooted()
    }
  }
}
```

use this code and everything work